# Spring REST does not return the objects' content

Tags: arrays, json, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I am using Spring Boot with a very simple RestController. The controller queries a MySQL Database and just before returning from the controller method I do see that a list of five employees are returned, each containing information about the employee.
However, querying the Spring Rest application with an HTTP-Get Request returns an array of five empty JSON structures:
Why?

My pom.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.luv2code.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>cruddemo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>20-hibernate-basic-cruddemo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

My Employee class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column
    private String email;
}
```

My RestController:

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.luv2code.spring.boot.cruddemo.dao.EmployeeDAO;
import com.luv2code.spring.boot.cruddemo.entity.Employee;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class EmployeeRestController {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeDAO employeeDAO;

    @GetMapping("/employees")
    public List<Employee> findAll() {
        List<Employee> employees = employeeDAO.findAll();
        return employees;
    }

}
```

When I put a breakpoint at the line

return employees;

I do see a five non-empty Employee objects like that:

[image]

But when querying with a browser's HTTP Get request I do receive a five empty JSON structures like that:
[image]

What is the problem?

Comment: Can you share the code for your `Employee` class? It may be missing the methods that a required for Jackson to turn it into the desired json.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson: done!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Andy Wilkinson:
I forgot the getters and the setters of the Employee class.
When I put them back, everything went OK!

AND: The reason why it worked with MySQL database, is because I am using field reflection in Hibernate, but obviously a setter reflection in JACKSON / for serializing as a JSON!

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to handle your error,
1 is to add loombook's getter setter
2 is to change private to public in Entity, good luck